# Quando usar Waterfall e quando usar Scrum?

Tags: gerenciamento-de-projetos, metodologia, scrum

Existe uma forma clara de determinar quando um projeto de desenvolvimento de software deve ser conduzido usando uma metodologia [Waterfall](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_em_cascata) ou usar [Scrum](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum)? Quais os critérios devem ser observados para escolher um ou outro?

Comment: Sobre quando usar o Scrum, isso é debatível. Mas sobre quando usar o Waterfall, essa é fácil: NUNCA!

Comment: Estamos em fase inicial do site e ainda precisamos determinar quais os tópicos podem ser abordados aqui na **nossa** comunidade. Dê sua opinião sobre os assuntos que são interessantes e os que devem ficar de fora votando em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/355/101

Comment: @HeadofCatering Aqui é o Stackoveflow **em português**

Comment: Acompanhando a pergunta, gostaria de saber quais as desvantagens de se adotar o método Waterfall.

Comment: É @bigown, a sua pergunta é muito legal e gosto dela, mas pensando bem, infelizmente do jeito que está ela é uma pergunta com respostas opinativas, e portanto deveria ser fechada (o que é no mínimo um fato curioso dado quem é o autor da questão). O que podemos fazer para dar um jeito nesse problema?

Comment: @Victor até concordo... em partes. Eu coloquei propositalmente para testar o que acontece, para haver um debate sobre ela. A pergunta nem é minha. Ela existe e é bem aceita em outro site da rede :) Qualquer que seja a decisão, no futuro vou poder usar ela como argumento para um lado ou para outro.

Comment: @Victor você está completamente enganado quanto a nunca se usar Waterfall. Existem situações em que modelos mais próximos do Waterfall encaixam bem e acabam sendo imprescindíveis. Tudo isso depende de diversos fatores dentro do seu ambiente de desenvolvimento que precisam ser analisados caso a caso.

Comment: Quanto a pergunta, não achei ela opinativa. É perfeitamente possível uma resposta objetiva para ela: Waterfall se encaixa melhor nessa situação e Scrum se encaixa melhor nessa situação. Se por acaso algum usuário vier apenas opinando subjetivamente na resposta (como no primeiro comentário dizendo para "nunca usar waterfall"), ele é que deveria receber votos negativos.

Comment: @FranciscoJunior até porque se a resposta for, hipoteticamente, "não existe uma forma clara por causa disso", ela será objetiva. E se existir, dizer qual é essa forma também é objetivo. Pode ter uma pouco de subjetividade, porém boa: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective

Comment: @FranciscoJunior É por isso que esse usuário não colocou uma resposta aqui, e sim apenas um comentário.

Comment: @FranciscoJunior Este mesmo usuário decidiu mudar de ideia e postou uma resposta. Obrigado pela inspiração.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bem, eu não pretendia responder, mas eis um comentário que Francisco Junior fez:

> Se por acaso algum usuário vier apenas opinando subjetivamente na resposta (como no primeiro comentário dizendo para "nunca usar waterfall"), ele é que deveria receber votos negativos.

Então vamos lá: Pode sentar o dedo no negativo aqui a esquerda!

De acordo com a [página sobre o modelo waterfall na wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model):

> The first formal description of the waterfall model is often cited as a 1970 article by Winston W. Royce, although Royce did not use the term "waterfall" in this article. Royce presented this model as an example of a flawed, non-working model.

Que traduzindo para o português é:

> A primeira definição formal do modelo waterfall é frequentemente apontada como sendo o artigo de Winston W. Royce de 1970, embora Royce não tenha usado o termo "waterfall" neste artigo. Royce apresentou este modelo como exemplo de um modelo falho e não-funcional.

Que interessante! O modelo waterfall já nasceu com a percepção de ser falho e não-funcional! E isso há mais de 40 anos atrás, então imagine hoje!

Bem, vamos dar uma olhada mais afundo no [artigo do Royce](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Process/waterfall.pdf):

> Figure 3 portrays the iterative relationship between successive development phases for this scheme. The ordering of steps is based on the following concept: that as each step progresses and the design is further detailed, there is an iteration with the preceding and succeeding steps but rarely with the more remote steps in the sequence.
>
> [...]
>
> I believe in this concept, but the implementation described above is risky and invites failure. The problem is illustrated in Figure 4. The testing phase which occurs at the end of the development cycle is the first event for which timing, storage, input/output transfers, etc., are experienced as distinguished from analyzed. [...], then invariably a major redesign is required. [...] The required design changes are likely to be so disruptive that the software requirements upon which the design is based and which provides the rationale for everything are violated. Either the requirements must be modified, or a substantial change in the design is required. In effect the development process has returned to the origin and one can expect up to a 100-percent overrun in schedule and/or costs.
>
> [...]
>
> Hopefully, the iterative interaction between the various phases is confined to successive steps.
>
> [...]
>
> Unfortunately, for the process illustrated, the design iterations are never confined to the successive steps.

Traduzindo para o português:

> A Figura 3 demonstra a relação iterativa entre sucessivas fases de desenvolvimento neste esquema. A ordenação dos passos é baseada no seguinte conceito: que cada passo é um progresso e o design é melhor detalhado, há uma iteração entre passos precedentes e sucedentes, mas raramente entre passos remotos na sequência.
>
> [...]
>
> Eu acredito neste conceito, mas a implementação descrita acima é arriscada e é um convite a falhar. O problema é ilustrado na Figura 4. A fase de teste que ocorre no final do ciclo de desenvolvimento é o primeiro evento para o qual o tempo, armazenamento transferência de entrada e saída, etc., revelam-se diferentes do que o que foi analisado. [...], e então invariavelmente um redesign pesado é necessário. [...] As mudanças necessárias no design serão provavelmente tão perturbadoras que os requisitos no qual o design foi feito e que proveem a razão para tudo foram violados. Ou os requisitos deverão ser modificados ou uma mudança substancial no design é necessária. O efeito é que o processo de desenvolvimento retornou à origem e então pode-se esperar um estouro de 100% no prazo e/ou nos custos.
>
> [...]
>
> Espera-se que a interação entre as várias fases seja confinada a passos sucessivos.
>
> [...]
>
> Infelizmente, para o processo ilustrado, as iterações demonstradas nunca estão confinadas a passos sucessivos.

[image: figura 3 do artigo original do Royce]

[image: figura 4 do artigo original do Royce]

Recomendo ler o artigo inteiro, e novamente friso que ele é do distante ano de 1970. Porém, isso continua assim até hoje, waterfall parte do preceito de que o desenvolvimento é composto por etapas rígidas e sequenciais, mas isso nunca funciona e todo mundo que já entrou em algum projeto nisso sabe porquê:

- O cliente muda de ideia a toda hora.
- O cliente não sabe o que quer.
- Surgiu um bug no teste e descobrimos que há um erro lá no começo do projeto.
- No meio do projeto acontece uma coisa e então temos que voltar e mudar um monte de coisa.
- O usuário não gostou do produto.
- O concorrente resolveu o problema de uma forma diferente e melhor.
- O cliente pediu mudanças em uma determinada parte, alterando um requisito importante.
- Existem dois ou mais requisitos em conflito.
- O cliente uma hora diz uma coisa e depois diz o contrário.
- Ocorreu um problema difícil de resolver no desenvolvimento e o prazo já foi pro saco.
- Etc.

Se quiser algo mais recente, é muuuuito, mas muuuuito fácil achar na internet, poderia facilmente citar Martin Fowler, práticas de TDD, ou até mesmo o livro Head First sobre desenvolvimento ágil, que lá dentro explica porquê que o waterfall não funciona.

E agora, para garantir o meu downvote, eu vou dar a minha observação pessoal sobre o que vemos hoje em dia: De fato, é difícil achar algum material que defenda o waterfall atualmente e que venha de alguém que tenha uma mínima ideia sobre o que está falando, e não apenas papagaiando conceitos antigos que nunca se deu o trabalho de questionar.

Na lista cima eu citei alguns motivos pelo qual o waterfall falha. Basicamente tudo se resume ao fato de que as coisas mudam ao longo do tempo. O que ontem era um requisito, hoje pode não ser mais. O que ontem não era importante, hoje é fundamental. Hoje nós temos uma restrição importante, mas amanhã não temos mais. É aí que as metodologias ágeis entram: elas foram pensadas em atacar estes problemas, assumindo que estas coisas mudam ao longo do tempo e bolando estratégias para que mudanças possam ser implementadas rapidamente.

Bem, confesso que até aqui só dei metade da resposta e não falei nada sobre scrum. Não vou entrar muito em detalhes do scrum e vou apenas fazer uma lista rápida para recomendar quando usar o metodologias ágeis (de forma mais genérica, seja scrum ou não) ou quando usar waterfall, e tenho certeza que depois que você ler isso e já ter dado o downvote, ainda vai chamar os seus amigos para também votarem contra:

- Se o seu escopo e os seus requisitos são inegocivelmente fechados, imutáveis e escritos em pedra, e o seu código é absolutamente perfeito e livre de bugs, você pode se dar bem com o waterfall. Caso contrário, eu recomendo o ágil.
- Se a sua função ou a função da sua empresa seja gerar milhões de páginas de documentos de requisitos, regras de negócio, decisões arquiteturais, fluxogramas, etc, e estes documentos não serão lidos e nem criticados por ninguém (ou pelo menos por ninguém que tenha o poder de ser ouvido), e não é você quem vai fazer o código, então o waterfall também é para você. Caso contrário recomendo o ágil.
- Se você planta bugs e requisitos mal-definidos de propósito no seu projeto para depois cobrar o cliente por qualquer mudança solicitada, então o waterfall também servirá para você. Caso contrário recomendo o ágil.
- Se a sua religião, sua filosofia, seu sentido de viver, ou a sua divindade favorita lhe diz que você deve seguir planos burocráticos e rigidamente definidos simplesmente porque as coisas sempre foram assim, são assim e sempre serão assim e que você tem a obrigação de ser feliz com isso sem nunca pensar em questionar, então recomendo o waterfall. Caso contrário recomendo o ágil.

Para finalizar, respondendo a este comentário:

> A propósito, certificações aeronáuticas necessitam de modelos formais de desenvolvimento. É muito mais provável que o software que rode nos aviões da Boeing, por exemplo, sejam desenvolvidos com um processo mais próximo do Waterfall do que de uma metodologia puramente ágil e informal como o Scrum. E lhe pergunto uma coisa: você prefere voar em um avião que tem certificação de software da FAA ou em um avião que foi desenvolvido sem qualquer formalidade com Scrum?

Como resposta a isso, digo que no dia 11/10/2013, assisti a uma palestra no IME/USP em São Paulo demonstrando o contrário. O título da palestra era "Combinando Scrum, AOP, DDD e Metadados – Um Caso de Sucesso na Embraer." e os palestrantes Roberto Perillo, Tiaslei Vasni e Daniel Feichas. Eis o resumo da palestra:

> Esta palestra consiste na apresentação da abordagem da criação de uma aplicação chamada AHEAD (Aircraft HEalth Analisys and Diagnosis), atualmente em andamento na área de Aviação Executiva na Embraer. A arquitetura da aplicação combina Domain-Driven Design, aspectos e metadados, cujo desenvolvimento está sendo gerenciado com SCRUM. Inicialmente, será mostrado um pequeno histórico de projetos na Embraer e porque foi decidida a utilização do SCRUM. Em seguida, serão mostrados alguns erros cometidos pela indústria de software (segundo a experiência dos membros da equipe) e os conceitos importantes para o entendimento da abordagem utilizada no design da aplicação. A seguir, serão apresentados os requisitos funcionais e não funcionais que motivaram a utilização da abordagem e como os elementos foram implementados. Será mostrado também como é o ambiente ALM que gerencia o ciclo de vida da aplicação e como foram organizados os testes (unidade, integração e sistema). Como exemplo, serão apresentadas questões relacionadas à implementação da segurança na aplicação, AJAX reverso por meio de eventos de domínio, interesses transversais e integração com outros sistemas. Na conclusão, serão apresentados os benefícios obtidos com a abordagem, como o ganho de flexibilidade na aplicação e a aceleração da velocidade da equipe no que diz respeito à produtividade.

Comment: Eu conheço alguns locais onde o Waterfall funciona muito bem há muito tempo, de forma que qualquer mudança, afetaria negativamente o funcionamento da equipe. O Waterfall é como a filosofia deles. Vamos ter cuidado pois cada caso é diferente. Mas, fiquemos cegos por um artigo :)

Comment: Sua visão de modelos de negócios diferentes do "cliente dá requisitos e eu faço para eles" é muito limitada. Nem todos os modelos de negócios são dessa forma. Nem toda empresa contrata outra apenas pelo software. Existem outros artefatos envolvidos: documentação, certificações (que geralmente necessitam um processo mais formal). Enfim. Seu sarcasmo só demonstra sua limitação em analisar racionalmente a questão.

Comment: A propósito, certificações aeronáuticas necessitam de modelos formais de desenvolvimento. É muito mais provável que o software que rode nos aviões da Boeing, por exemplo, sejam desenvolvidos com um processo mais próximo do Waterfall do que de uma metodologia puramente ágil e informal como o Scrum. E lhe pergunto uma coisa: você prefere voar em um avião que tem certificação de software da FAA ou em um avião que foi desenvolvido sem qualquer formalidade com Scrum?

Comment: Francisco Junior, já vi uma palestra na USP de um pessoal que desenvolvia sistemas de aviônica para a Embraer. Eles usam scrum com TDD e DDD.

Comment: É difícil comentar algo como "vi uma palestra de um cara que usava". Mas eu diria que não usaram. Se você considera Waterfall apenas como sua primeira definição e ignora todas as suas adaptações, você também deve considerar Scrum assim. E se é assim, eles não usam. Ou se usam sem modificações, não certificam o software. Existem características intrínsecas da DO-178 (certificação aeronáutica) que o Scrum não leva em consideração, como rastreablidade. É necessário adaptar o Scrum para isso (da mesma forma que é possível adaptar o Waterfall para ter ciclos de desenvolvimento).

Comment: @FranciscoJunior Se você está adaptando o Waterfall para ter ciclos de desenvolvimento, então já não é mais Waterfall! O Scrum é bastante flexível (isso faz parte do propósito dele), então não há problema nenhum em adaptá-lo para que possa atender a certificação que seja, a ideia dele é exatamente a de possibilitar adaptações rápidas à mudanças e a particularidades de cada situação, mas sem sacrificar a ideia de ciclos rápidos e curtos de desenvolvimento (sprints) com histórias, estimativas e backlogs. E rastreabilidade é requisito de software não característica do processo de desenvolvimento.

Comment: @FranciscoJunior Aumentei um pouquinho a minha resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, tentei por as imagens do artigo para que sua resposta ficasse melhor de se ler. Caso discorde, desfaça a vontade

Answer (score 17):

Vou arriscar a contribuir para esse assunto polêmico, principalmente após ler a resposta do Victor. Quero refutar o argumento dele, mas ao mesmo tempo concordar plenamente com ele. Como?

## *Waterfall* está em todo lugar

Primeiramente, todos os desenvolvedores usam *Waterfall*. Sempre. O que muda é a escala.

Não podemos burlar a sequência `Requisito > Análise > Design > Implementação > Teste > Integração`, simplesmente porque é impossível. Como podemos fazer análise sem requisitos, implementação sem saber o que temos que fazer ou teste sem código?

A diferença é que alguns tentam fazer tudo numa sequência, escrevem grandes blocos de código e tentam fazer rodar tudo de uma só vez. Outros, mais como o meu caso, testam o código a cada ou duas ou três linhas modificadas ou acrescentadas.

Então, posso conciliar minhas afirmações fazendo uma diferença entre um *Waterfall Completo* e um *Micro Waterfall*. Concordando com o Victor, é simplesmente impossível fazer um *Waterfall Completo* em um projeto de software porque sempre será necessário revisar erros e mudanças que afetam as etapas anteriores. Mesmo para corrigir um pequeno bug você precisa analisar os requisitos, fazer design de uma solução, implementá-la, testá-la. Por outro lado, o que processos ágeis fazem é diminuir o quanto for possível os *time boxes* para obter *feedback* do cliente, criando assim *Micro Waterfalls*.

## Projetos com aparência de *Waterfall*

Na prática, projetos pode ser "interfaceados* com o cliente com base no modelo *Waterfall Completo* e micro gerenciados na equipe de desenvolvimento usando Scrum ou qualquer outra metodologia de gerenciamento ágil.

Para alguns clientes, **não** é interessante obter um produto muito cedo. Pensei no caso de uma mudança de lei com data para entrar em vigor. O que adianta receber o produto antes? Um projeto com um cronograma *Waterfall* caberia bem nesse caso. Entretanto, nada impede que o desenvolvimento seja feito com princípios ágeis, onde a cada uma ou duas semanas as funcionalidades são integradas numa versão executável, testada usando *mocks*, apresentada para um cliente (mesmo que não seja o cliente em si, mas um especialista em negócios).

## Não podemos ter tudo

Há algum tempo escrevi um artigo sobre o [triângulo de ferro](http://luizricardo.eti.br/2013/09/entendendo-o-triangulo-de-ferro-porque-nao-podemos-ter-tudo/). A ideia desta representação é passar a ideia de projetos de software lidam com restrições intrínsecas que não podemos simplesmente ignorar. As comumente citadas são: tempo, recursos, escopo e qualidade.

Metodologias mais tradicionais de desenvolvimento e gerenciamento de software, onde o *Waterfall* se enquadra muito bem, geralmente tendem a fixar tempo e escopo. O que acontece? Calcula-se o número de recursos necessários para entregar o sistema numa data, as coisas não andam como o planejado e quem sofre é a qualidade.

Processos modernos, que geralmente levam o termo "incremental e iterativo" até o limite, seguem um caminho inverso. Eles geralmente variam o escopo (acrescentando ou tirando *user stories* da *sprint* de acordo com a produtividade) para manter o tempo fixo e a qualidade num patamar aceitável.

## Considerações finais

Enfim, meu conselho geral seria:

- Para desenvolvimento de software, nunca use *Waterfall* no sentido completo do modelo, pois seria completamente inviável.
- Quando, e somente quando, o cliente ou a situação exigir um cronograma rígido, encapsule o desenvolvimento em um projeto com aparência de *Waterfall*, mas tendo muita consciência de que, quando fixamos o tempo e o escopo, prejudicamos a qualidade. [Não podemos ter tudo.](http://luizricardo.eti.br/2013/09/entendendo-o-triangulo-de-ferro-porque-nao-podemos-ter-tudo/)

Comment: Essa me parece a melhor resposta. Faz muito sentido a ideia de que qualquer abordagem moderna é uma forma evoluida de análise em cascata, assim como o argumento de que o uso completo e rígido do *Waterfall* é equivocado. O problema principal de qualquer área da Engenharia é o entendimento do problema, e há grande dificuldade na comunicação entre cliente e desenvolvedor especialmente no caso de Software (por isso casos de uso são desenhos tão infantis). Nada melhor para mitigar dúvidas a respeito do "que o cliente realmente quer" do que protótipos funcionais que são gradualmente completados.

Answer (score 13):

Pra mim, a linha divisória está em "grau de certeza" que se tem do projeto. Projetos que sabe-se exatamente o que construir, waterfall encaixa muito bem (ex.: prédios). Projetos em que existe grande grau de incerteza sobre o que fazer e aprende-se muito durante o projeto, o Scrum se encaixa melhor.

O post [Levantamento de requisitos e SCRUM](http://ericlemes.com/2013/09/29/requisitos-metodologias-ageis/) fala um pouco de como o tema "levantamento de requisitos" é abordado em metodologias ágeis.

Ao contrário do Waterfall em que mudanças não são bem-vindas (pois geram "change requests" e demandam revisão de todo  o projeto),  o ágil encoraja as mudanças. Logo, quando o objetivo do projeto é algo fácil de tangibilizar no início do projeto (é fácil prever todas as atividades, prazos, etc), o waterfall se encaixa muito mais. No caso de requisitos difíceis, mais experimentais, o ágil lida melhor, princialmente pois ele encoraja priorizar o que se conhece menos, mitigando o risco do projeto não ser entregue sprint a sprint.

Por essa razão, o scrum geralmente encaixa-se muito bem em projetos de software. No início do projeto, existe muita incerteza que é reduzida pouco a  pouco. Conforme as entregas iterativas recebem feedback do usuário, as melhorias nas funcionalidades são estimadas (em novas estórias), e entram novamente no backlog para serem  priorizadas.

A gestão do prazo começa a ser mais eficiente, pois à  medida que o time vai gerando histórico de "velocidade" (quantas estórias, de quantos pontos são realizadas dentro de uma sprint), sabe-se pelo tamanho do backlog x velocidade qual a previsão de conclusão do projeto.

Em contrapartida, no waterfall, a cultura de cravar datas em pedra acaba imperando, pois para não perder os prazos, as mudanças são desencorajadas. Ao complicar as renegociações de escopo (em cada mudança, todo o encadeamento de atividades, e todo o cronograma deveria ser revisto), o resultado acaba sendo produtos que não são de interesse do usuário, ou o prazo para sua construção é tão  grande que ao terminar o projeto, os requisitos dados no início do projeto não mais refletem a necessidade do usuário.

Uma outra referência interessante sobre o assunto está no livro "Agile principles, patterns and practices", do Robert C. Martin (apêndice B). Neste livro ele uma comparação entre o tempo de "documentação" (ou projeto) x o tempo de construção. Neste exercício, o autor sugere que na construção civil, por exemplo, o custo do projeto é uma fração do custo total de construção e uma vez pronto o projeto, sabe-se exatamente o que construir. Em software, o "modelo", seria o próprio código fonte, enquanto que a construção apenas a "compilação" do software, a construção. Neste caso, o tempo de projeto é quase que todo o tempo do projeto. Nestes cenários, o ágil se enquadra melhor.

Comment: Você poderia elaborar um pouco mais aqui? Parece interessante mas a resposta está muito perto de ser apenas um link que não é adequado para um sites de perguntas e respostas.

Comment: Seria legal complementar a resposta, poderia fazer um resumo do link do site que você passou como referência?

Answer (score 5):

## Quando usar Waterfall?

Quando os requisitos são bem definidos e sem perspectiva de mudança, como a construção de um prédio. Ou seja, muito raramente no caso de software.

Com a ressalva que boas metodologias de desenvolvimento de software costumam ser iterativas e podem definir um modelo semelhante ao waterfall como procedimento de cada iteração, embora o processo como um todo não seja Waterfall.

---

## Quando usar Scrum?

Vou usar as características do Scrum para determinar quando é adequado utilizá-lo.

**Dica:** Se você vai se casar, pode usar Scrum para [organizar o casamento](https://www.google.com.br/#q=scrum+wedding+planning). :)

### Scrum é acima de tudo Ágil

O Scrum é uma das formas de se implementar [metodologias ágeis](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desenvolvimento_%C3%A1gil_de_software); isso define a maior parte do que é o Scrum e como tal ele adota as preferências do **Manifesto Ágil**:

> - **Indivíduos e interações** em preferência a **Processos e ferramentas**
> - **Software funcionando** em preferência a **Documentação extensiva**
> - **Colaboração do cliente** em preferência a **Negociação de contrato**
> - **Reagir a mudanças** em preferência a **Seguir um plano**

Isso não quer dizer que os critérios do lado direito serão ignorados, mas sim que os do lado esquerdo são preferidos em relação a eles.

A adoção do **Manifesto Ágil** sugere um perfil de projeto para o qual o Scrum (e demais implementações de métodos ágeis) se adequa melhor:

- Quando há expectativa de que os requisitos mudem ao longo do desenvolvimento;
- Quando o cliente está disponível para fornecer *feedback* ao processo de desenvolvimento;
- Quando documentar formalmente o processo de desenvolvimento não é crítico para o projeto;
- Quando não é necessário que a metodologia em si determine o tipo de documentação gerada por ela.

### Scrum tem características próprias

Algumas características específicas do Scrum refinam esse perfil de projeto:

- Equipes relativamente pequenas, fisicamente próximas e capazes de se auto-organizarem;
- Prazo mínimo de uma *sprint* para desenvolver o produto.

### Situações em que o Scrum brilha (em comparação a métodos não-ágeis):

- Por ser iterativo, baseado em *sprints* e responder rápido a mudanças, o Scrum garante que as mudanças vão ser atendidas da forma mais rápida possível, obedecendo a uma fila de prioridades e entregando o máximo de *deliverables* que a(s) equipe(s) têm capacidade de entregar dentro desse contexto. Ele mostra seu melhor quando o cliente, além de se preocupar em dispor dessa capacidade de resposta rápida, está ciente da importância de sua própria disponibilidade para fornecer *feedback* à(s) equipe(s), e deseja ter iterações do produto (entregas parciais) funcionando o mais rápido possível;
- Quando as entregas não podem sair do prazo. Isso porque as *sprints* têm duração pré-definida (embora seja possível cancelar entregas).

---

**Nota:** Especialistas em Scrum por favor complementem/corrijam o que foi citado, pois a minha experiência como Scrum é inferior a um ano e apenas como desenvolvedor ([porco](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Galinha_e_o_Porco)).

Answer (score 2):

No Scrum e outros métodos ágeis a participação do cliente (Product Owner) é necessária o tempo todo. Nestes métodos, quando mais o cliente puder interagir de dar feedback para o desenvolvedor melhor será o software produzido, ou seja, o software produzido será mais adequado às necessidades do cliente.

Se, por algum motivo, o cliente não puder estar presente o tempo todo, o Scrum ou outro método ágil fica inviabilizado ou, pelo menos, prejudicado. Aí, provavelmente você vai cair num modelo mais próximo do Cascata (requisitos --> desenvolvimento --> validação).

Mais como regra geral, quanto mais interação e mais feedback melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Eu recomendo se apoiar na matriz de Stacey, que ajuda a visualizar que quando você tem bastante conhecimento do que será feito e acordo com os envolvidos, o cascata pode servir bem.

Quando você não tem tanta clareza / acordo, o ágil pode servir melhor pois te ajudará a testar e validar pequenas opções ao longo do projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

**Quando usar o Waterfall**

- O Ciclo de vida Waterfall é utilizado principalmente quando o software a ser construído é definido matematicamente e/ou formalmente onde todos os seus requisitos e lógica são previamente estabelecidos e checados matematicamente como o freio ABS. (Logo é de extrema necessidade que o cliente se comprometa com a especificação de requisitos).
- Obs: Softwares de suporte a vida devem ser homologados por uma instituição especializada, logo sua documentação dever ser bem estruturada (o que é um requisito para o uso de Waterfall).

**Quando usar o Scrum**

- Quando se é necessário uma entrega de funcionalidades para o cliente em um prazo muito curto (logo é escalonado as prioridade de cada função, a prioridade define a ordem de entrega).
- Quando o cliente não tem total certeza de suas necessidades.
- Quando o domínio da aplicação está em constante mudança.
- Quando a equipe for **pequena (+/- 10 membros)** e tiver bom entrosamento. (Requisito determinante).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Fonte:https://www.seguetech.com/waterfall-vs-agile-methodology/]

Caro, colega, é muito difícil responder à sua pergunta sem emitir algum juízo de valor nem entrar em argumentações complexas. É uma decisão que pode depender de muitos fatores.

Porém, para que não fique sem resposta objetiva e como orientação básica comparativa, sugiro que avalie a tabela acima que resume bem alguns aspectos (prós e contras) famosos de ambas abordagens.

Fonte: https://www.seguetech.com/waterfall-vs-agile-methodology/

Comment: Eu particularmente não enxerguei diferencial de sua resposta às outras anteriores. Poderia tornar mais claro o que sua resposta distingue-se das demais?