# Em que momento de um projeto se deve escolher a plataforma?

Tags: gerenciamento-de-projetos, projeto-de-software

Quando um projeto é concebido (i.e. uma necessidade é identificada, e se decide por desenvolver uma solução informatizada para a mesma) uma das primeiras coisas que o cliente pergunta é: em que plataforma o software deve ser desenvolvido? Em que linguagem de programação? Como sabemos, não existe uma resposta única, mas é difícil explicar isso para quem é leigo no assunto. E muitas vezes somos cobrados por uma definição antes mesmo do projeto começar.

Tirando alguns casos "óbvios" (ex.: a equipe que vai desenvolver já está formada, e todos os profissionais só dominam uma única plataforma), qual é o melhor momento para se tomar essa decisão? Na faculdade, aprendi que o ideal é fazê-lo ao fim da [fase de elaboração](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processo_unificado) (i.e. quando a especificação e análise dos requisitos estiver concluída), quando quaisquer restrições ao design já estarão identificadas. Mas na prática não sei se isso funcionaria - haja vista a [tendência de se adotar metodologias ágeis em detrimento das tradicionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3274/215). Ainda assim, me parece um erro dizer "vamos programar em X" antes mesmo de conhecer as características particulares da aplicação.

Se não existe nenhuma razão em particular para se escolher entre uma tecnologia e outra, deve-se "bater o martelo" antes mesmo de tudo começar? Ou existe um ponto mais específico no projeto em que essa decisão é mais adequada?

**Nota:** Pra pergunta não ficar muito ampla, estou buscando por argumentos de natureza técnica, e não de mercado (ex.: disponibilidade de profissionais com formação específica pra contratação, salário médio dos mesmos, etc).

Answer (score 5):

Vou pedir tua permissão para não responder a pergunta de maneira exata. Acho que é mais fácil pensarmos nas **características que influenciam** a escolha da plataforma:

- **Deploy**: como o software vai ser entregue e consumido? Pode ser um software de prateleira, uma aplicação web para dispositivos móveis, uma aplicação web para computadores, um app, um aplicativo local...
- **Ambiente**: muito similar ao deploy, mas em sequência. Há requisitos de ambiente para rodar a aplicação? Servidores Linux ou Windows, integração com ferramentas específicas (rede Novell, servidor Exchange...). Alguma questão de licenciamento, talvez?
- **Equipe**: daí sim, acho que entra o ponto que você já falou. Vamos montar uma equipe ou já temos o pessoal? Qual o expertise deles?

Aqui há duas referências interessantes:

- [Gov.UK - Choosing technology](https://www.gov.uk/service-manual/making-software/choosing-technology.html)
- [How to choose the most suitable technologies for your project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125306/how-to-choose-the-most-suitable-technologies-for-your-project)

Trouxe esta reflexão porque, se pensarmos nas questões que apresentei aqui, vamos ver que elas nem sempre são tratadas nas mesmas etapas do projeto. Portanto, responder exatamente o **momento** para escolha da plataforma é temeroso.

Comment: Mas você **está** respondendo à pergunta! :) É desse tipo de questionamento que eu preciso, pois (no meu caso particular) tudo que tenho é uma visão bem geral do que o sistema vai ser, e o cliente [em potencial] já quer sair escolhendo a plataforma. Estabelecer parâmetros para orientar a escolha, e principalmente comunicar esses parâmetros, esse é o X da questão! (e reiterando: as características de mercado contam sim, e muito, só deixei de fora do escopo da questão para que não fique muito ampla)

Comment: @mgibsonbr É que eu não fui diretamente ao título da pergunta :) Conheço essa situação em que você está, é difícil controlar a ansiedade (ou intromissão) do cliente. Avise se quiser que eu amplie a resposta com outras considerações.

Answer (score 2):

Cada linguagem resolve um problema, mas em 99% dos casos a decisão ficará restrita a linguagens mais comuns (digamos que fique entre .net e Java). Nesse caso, a decisão deve levar em consideração a infraestrutura da empresa: é mais voltada para Windows? Nossos bancos são SQL Server? Ou estamos mais voltados para ambiente livre? Tudo isso influi.

Por outro lado, se tiver um ambiente agnóstico, a escolha de plataforma acaba caindo sobre o expertise da equipe. Se sua equipe ainda precisa ser formada, acaba sendo uma decisão filosófica.

Há que se tomar cuidado com vaidades, também, não que haja algo errado nisso. Um xiita de .net pode criar como argumento defeitos que Java não tem, e vice versa. Tudo isso pode impactar negativamente em um contratante, por mais que a "vitória" do argumento seja conseguida naquele momento.

Em suma: a escolha da melhor linguagem passa pela escolha das melhores pessoas, o que é um assunto **bem** mais extenso.

Answer (score 2):

Do ponto de vista técnico, creio que devemos classificar os diferentes domínios de soluções (webapp, desktop, webservice, batch, móvel, ...) para as quais as diversas linguagens podem ser mais ou menos eficientes.

Com essa ideia em mente, a escolha da linguagem/plataforma/framework pode ser feita assim que se consegue identificar esse domínio, isto é, o "tipo" do sistema ser desenvolvido.

Dificilmente um projeto vai divergir muito de algo que já exista, cujas soluções em cada plataforma também são conhecidas, então muitas vezes podemos ter uma resposta logo no primeiro contato.

Isso está bem relacionado às estimativas: quanto mais conhecido é aquele domínio, mais exatas as previsões serão. Então, no caso de um projeto cujo domínio é pouco conhecido, convém um tempo maior de pesquisa, até a definição do que será desenvolvido.

Em parte, eu rejeito a ideia de que a linguagem é uma escolha de importância maior, pelo menos para os domínios mais comuns.

Tomemos as **aplicações web** como exemplo, quase todas as linguagens possuem soluções robustas para criá-las. Não vejo proposições objetivas para dizer que Java é melhor que C#, que é melhor que Python, que é melhor que Ruby, que é melhor que PHP e assim por diante. Lógico que existem exceções, tal como C ou ShellScript, as quais não seriam as melhores respostas para sistemas web dinâmicos no mundo atual.

Existe uma certa relação `N:N` entre o domínio da solução e as diferentes linguagens. Desde que o domínio tenha sido corretamente identificado, não há porque postergar a escolha da plataforma.

O problema maior reside na limitação da equipe ou líder do projeto em saber quais as opções possíveis de solução para cada domínio. O que ocorre é a escolha repetida por soluções já utilizadas em projetos anteriores. Embora nem sempre seja a escolha mais adequada, algumas vezes isso pode ser compensado pelo ganho de produtividade adquirido nas experiências anteriores.

Particularmente, eu acabo limitando meus projetos e trabalhos a certos domínios, no caso, sistemas web. Em geral, eu rejeitaria um projeto onde a solução seria Desktop, pois haveria um grande *overhead* para assimilar as particularidades de tal projeto.

Answer (score 2):

**Em que momento a plataforma deve ser escolhida? No início**.

**Ela pode mudar no meio do projeto? Sim**, pode caso o custo e tempo de desenvolvimento seja menor do que continuar com a estratégia inicial. Para ficar mais lógico o impacto da estratégia, vou citar rapidamente a respeito da escolha da plataforma.

### Listagem por ordem de importância **como** escolher uma plataforma

1. **A plataforma, obrigatoriamente, deve teoricamente permitir que a solução seja desenvolvida nela**. Estudos de casos parecidos são ideais, mas não obrigatórios
2. **Plataforma escolhida deve, obrigatoriamente, ter recursos humanos pré-habilitados, ainda que por contratação adicional, ou considerar no prazo a habilitação**.
3. **A plataforma deve ou ser focada no seu tipo de projeto, ou ter bibliotecas que facilitem o seu tipo de projeto, e custo devem ser aceitáveis**
4. **A plaforma deve permitir o desenvolvimento do software minimamente funcional antes das outras opções** (*varia com contexto*)
5. **A plataforma deve ter uma manutenibilidade melhor que as demais** (*varia com contexto*)

Deve ser levado em consideração que, no caso de projetos mais complexos, mais de uma plataforma pode ser escolhida, o que pode reduzir severamente custos como tempo de desenvolvimento. **Pegar o melhor de cada plataforma e apenas desenvolver integração entre plataformas diferentes é uma boa opção**.

---

### Exemplos práticos

**Um comercio eletrônico que precisa de um blog**, que tem prazos apertados e poucos recursos humanos, poderia contratar um software como serviço que cuidaria da plataforma de e-commerce, porém o blog, por ter recursos pessoais mais fácies de conseguir e o tempo de desenvolvimento seria menor, poderia usar um certo software popular de blog. Caso precisasse de newsletter, poderia usar algum serviço popular que tem preços acessíveis para volumes não muito altos (ex.: até 20 mil contatos) e uma interface simples de administrar para uma pessoa não técnica.

**Um comercio eletrônico de uma empresa enorme**, poderia contratar uma equipe multi-disciplinar para fazer um e-commerce sob medida, com exigências bem específicas de interface e de otimização para mecanismos de busca. Porém outros recursos, como análise de dados seria prudente não ser desenvolvido do zero, mas sim usar algum software de Business Intelligence. O sistema de newsletter também poderia ser só uma integração com a compra de licença paga de um certo produto muito usado da área, porém o envio dos e-mails sair de servidores próprios, por questões de redução de custos para envio em massa.

**Por que então é importante já iniciar com pelo menos uma ideia de quais plataformas serão usadas?**

Os dois exemplos acima estrategicamente escolheram múltiplas plataformas conforme os 5 itens que passei. Então vem a pergunta: o que aconteceria se as decisões fossem adiadas? Bem, a tendência natural é querer fazer tudo na plataforma inicial, o que tende fortemente a gerar custos porque sem a gerencia certa, todos os projetos tendem fortemente a querer reinventar a roda. Por isso é bom sim prever tão logo seja possível quais plataformas serão usadas, mas ter em mente que isso deve ser reconsiderado caso uma previsão anterior errou significativamente.

Answer (score 2):

## Último momento responsável (*last responsible moment*)

Tendo em vista que existem muitas possibilidades e variáveis envolvidas, melhor é adotar um princípio, uma heurística, em vez de uma regra bem-definida. 
Convém considerar o *Last Responsible Moment* https://dzone.com/articles/lean-tools-last-responsible.

Há uma afirmação curiosa na pergunta. Nela lê-se, ao final, "se não existe nenhuma razão em particular para se escolher entre uma tecnologia e outra...". Observe que, se de fato, não existe, então a escolha é irrelevante e, naturalmente, o momento em que ocorre (quando) também é irrelevante, desde que não seja após o último momento responsável.