# Como fazer o orçamento inicial de um projeto de software?

Tags: gerenciamento-de-projetos

**Contexto:** Fui "educado" na metodologia do [Processo Unificado](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processo_unificado). Sei que Agile é muito popular hoje em dia, mas tenho pouquíssimo conhecimento do processo. Entendo a filosofia que "mudanças são inevitáveis, é melhor se preparar pra lidar bem com elas do que tentar evitá-las", mas isso não é muito consolo quando sou cobrado a apresentar um orçamento - mesmo que inicial - para um projeto de desenvolvimento. Pelo UP, primeiro se orça a elaboração do projeto conceitual (que é uma simples questão de estimar o número de horas necessárias para se levantar e analisar todos os requisitos, e com poucas consequências negativas caso se erre no julgamento) e com base neste se orça o projeto de implementação. Na teoria, parece tudo muito bom, mas me falta experiência prática para corroborar essa afirmação.

**Problema:** Sei que a resposta correta para "como orçar um projeto de software" é: "depende"; depende do escopo, depende dos requisitos específicos, depende do cliente... Mas o fato é que clientes em potencial demandam no mínimo uma previsão preliminar de prazos e custos ([e às vezes plataforma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6776/215)), antes mesmo dos requisitos serem detalhados. Minha dificuldade é em estabelecer esses parâmetros iniciais, ou mesmo ajustar minhas expectativas sobre o que é ou não realizável na prática.

**Pergunta:** Quais parâmetros devo observar para fazer um orçamento **inicial** (ou preliminar) para um projeto arbitrário de desenvolvimento? Mais especificamente:

- Devo cobrar pelo levantamento inicial de requisitos/definição do escopo, ou esse é um ônus que terei de assumir?

  - E se a resposta for "não cobrar", devo insistir com o cliente que não é possível orçar nada antes de fazer esse levantamento? (o cliente não vai gostar - uma vez que levantar requisitos exige envolvimento de sua equipe também, o que lhe traz custos indiretos antes mesmo de ter a certeza que vai mesmo fechar contrato conosco)
- No caso de um projeto de grande escopo (embora ainda bastante indefinido), devo separá-lo em um projeto conceitual e um projeto de implementação? Ou isso é contraproducente?

  - Esclarecendo: projeto conceitual é aquele em que eu faço levantamento e análise de requisitos, sendo que o *deliverable* é uma especificação mais orçamento para a fase de implementação; o projeto de implementação - esse já feito com bases mais sólidas - pode sim ser flexível em relação a mudanças, não precisando seguir a especificação a ferro e fogo. Mas ainda precisa de uma base para ser orçado, e essa base seria conseguida através do projeto conceitual.
  - Por que seria contraproducente? Não sei! Apenas é o que sempre ouço dos proponentes do Agile: que é besteira fazer projeto [de grande escala] antes de se começar a implementar (ao menos um "sprint" deveria estar previsto), que os requisitos mudam o tempo todo e no final pouco do que foi projetado no início será implementado de fato, etc.
- Em que **termos** deve ser feito esse orçamento? Idealmente, mudanças nos requisitos deveriam refletir em mudanças nos prazos e custos (nisso a turma do UP e a turma do Agile concordam), mas se contratualmente estou obrigado a entregar X no prazo Y mediante pagamento de Z, não me parece viável haver uma mudança contratual toda vez que se fizer uma renegociação de prazos e custos.

  - Questões jurídicas à parte (já que isso está obviamente fora do escopo do site), o que eu pergunto é se é melhor fazer um "guesstimate" (de preferência, por cima) do custo e ir refinando com o passar do tempo (porém comprometido com a conclusão do projeto a todo custo), ou se devo estabelecer condições para que - na impossibilidade de se continuar o projeto dentro dos prazos e custos estabelecidos - o mesmo seja encerrado de comum acordo por ambas as partes (*como* fazer isso, é claro, é responsabilidade do nosso advogado).

De preferência, gostaria de respostas embasadas em experiência pregressa (sei que nem todo desenvolvedor está diretamente envolvido com esse tipo de questão, mas ao menos os que ocupam uma posição de liderança já devem ter tido que fazer estimativas sob bases incertas). E para não ficar muito amplo, o ponto central da pergunta é: o **quanto** eu devo assumir de ônus ao estabelecer um escopo/preparar uma proposta de graça, e quais são os parâmetros mínimos que eu preciso coletar antes de dizer: "a partir daqui, só me pagando".

Comment: Nota: embora essa pergunta seja tangencial a ["gerência de projeto"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/355/215), ela difere no sentido que se trata mais de um "anteprojeto" - algo que precisa acontecer antes de uma oportunidade virar proposta que vai virar projeto - mas ainda é algo que envolve diretamente o desenvolvedor. Por essa razão, abri [um novo item "orçamento/questões de contratação" no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1646/215), se acha que esse tipo de pergunta deva ser on ou off topic, dê sua opinião lá! No mais, espero não ter ficado amplo/subjetivo demais...

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: ["Making a budget and time plan for a software project"](http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/1468) no [programmers.se]

Comment: Do ponto de vista ágil, este artigo coloca uma visão interessante http://blog.dtisistemas.com.br/como-orcar-um-projeto-agil-2/.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Escopo e Estimação

O orçamento de um projeto de software está envolvido diretamente com a capacidade de definir o escopo e estimar o esforço necessário para desenvolver a solução. E qualquer analista com um mínimo de experiência sabe que são duas coisas extremamente difíceis de fazer com acurácia.

O objetivo durante a fase de iniciação de projeto, da qual depende o orçamento, é chegar a um consenso mais próximo possível da realidade sobre o que deverá ser feito.

As duas partes são muito interessadas na correta estimação, de forma a minimizar o **risco** do projeto. Esta é a palavra-chave aqui.

Se o projeto for estimado a menos, os imprevistos que surgirão poderão inviabilizá-lo, além de se perder o *time to market*. Se for estimado a mais, é possível que o cliente desista de um projeto que, de outra forma, teria sucesso ou ainda que outros projetos sejam prejudicados, já que a força de trabalho será desnecessariamente alocada.

## Mudança de escopo

Processos "tradicionais" (como o RUP) e ágeis possuem mecanismos para lidar com as inevitáveis mudanças de escopo e mitigar os riscos.

O RUP, por exemplo, mitiga os maiores riscos primeiro através da prototipação dos requisitos mais complexos e gerando uma arquitetura executável na fase de elaboração.

Metodologias ágeis fazem esta mitigação através de entregas constantes, às vezes semanais. Elas também procuram postergar decisões de projeto com base na ideia de que quanto antes algo for definido, mais difícil será mudar depois (engessamento).

A principal diferença no que se refere à mudanças é que, enquanto elas são muitas vezes tratadas como casos excepcionais nos processos "tradicionais", nas metodologias ágeis são a regra.

## Escopo aberto ou fechado?

Há algum tempo escrevi um [artigo sobre o Triângulo de Ferro](http://luizricardo.org/2013/09/entendendo-o-triangulo-de-ferro-porque-nao-podemos-ter-tudo/) para tentar explicar que, num projeto de software, *não podemos ter tudo*.

[image: Triângulo de Ferro]

O cliente e alguns gerentes querem que entreguemos tudo (escopo), rápido (tempo), barato (custo) e com qualidade. Mas isso é impossível!

O conceito do Triângulo serve justamente para demonstrar que devemos fazer escolhas, mesmo que inconscientemente.

Por várias razões, o desenvolvimento "normal" é feito com escopo, tempo e custo fixos. Isso significa que quando há imprevistos, a qualidade é sacrificada.

Métodos ágeis *tentam* fixar a qualidade e manter o escopo variável. Isso significa que se uma funcionalidade não "couber" no *sprint* atual, ela pode ser postergada.

Além disso, se os desenvolvedores entregam uma versão funcional do sistema a cada final de *sprint*, então o cliente pode decidir por prolongar o projeto para incluir mais funcionalidades ou encurtá-lo, se considerar que o sistema já está bom o suficiente para produção. Isso é apoiado por algumas pesquisas (careço de fontes) que demonstram que os usuários não chegam a usar a maioria das funções de um sistema.

No mundo ideal do *agile*, o cliente não precisaria receber um orçamento final de todo o projeto. Seria feito o planejamento num horizonte relativamente curto.

O problema disso é que se o cliente quer manter o escopo fixo, então o custo e o tempo seriam variáveis, já que novos *sprints* ocorreriam até que o escopo fosse completamente implementado.

## Estimação

Postergar decisões e a estimação é bom porque os requisitos tornam-se mais claros no decorrer do projeto. Pelo menos num cenário ideal. Isso é bem representado pelo Cone da Incerteza:

[image: Cone da Incerteza]

O problema é que isso não ajuda numa estimação inicial do projeto! Mesmo nos métodos ágeis são realizadas sessões de estimação inicial para possibilitar a venda do projeto.

No fim das contas, tudo se resume à capacidade dos profissionais de estimar. Isso envolve tempo, que, por sua vez, envolve custo.

## Esforço para estimação

Quanto esforço despender para a estimação? É uma questão complexa, mas muitos autores concordam que não pode ser pouco nem muito.

[image: Gráfico de Acurácia por Esforço]

### Projetos de escopo "pequeno"

Para projetos pequenos, principalmente quando o processo de desenvolvimento já foi repetido várias vezes, não há muita discussão.

Pense em websites, por exemplo. Um *webdesigner* certamente consegue visualizar a maioria das atividades de um "projeto de website" enquanto conversa com o cliente. Não há complexidade o suficiente que impeça o desenvolvedor de criar um modelo mental do problema.

### Projetos de escopo "grande"

Vamos considerar projetos de escopo "grande" aqueles onde a complexidade é tal que torna impossível um único profissional ter em mente todo o projeto.

Nesses casos, em minha experiência, as melhores estimativas acontecem quando os requisitos são avaliados pela equipe de desenvolvimento e discute-se a implementação de cada um deles. Nunca vi estimativas boas feitas por um "estimador profissional", gerente de projeto ou por um único analista.

Mas, na prática, não é viável interromper o trabalho de várias pessoas para cada nova proposta.

## Pré-estimativa

Uma solução que as empresas adotam para projetos grandes é fazer uma pré-estimativa. Esta seria uma análise superficial do problema envolvendo poucos especialistas, de modo a gerar uma faixa de valores dentre os quais o custo final deve ficar.

O conceito de **faixa de valores** é muito importante. Como pode ser observado no Cone da Incerteza, essa faixa acaba sendo grande no começo. A acurácia do resultado depende da experiência dos profissionais e de quantos projetos semelhantes já foram desenvolvidos.

Das empresas que conheço, nenhuma cobra por uma pré-estimativa. É um risco que elas tomam para si, diluindo o custo disso nos projetos efetivamente contratados.

Se houver excesso de solicitações de pré-estimativas, pode-se filtrar as propostas de projetos segundo alguns critérios:

- Verificar se o projeto está de acordo com o perfil da empresa contratada. Se a empresa tem foco em soluções *mobile*, talvez não seja viável despender tempo com propostas de aplicações *desktop*.
- Verificar o perfil do cliente. É um cliente "estratégico", isto é, que já contratou ou tem previsão de contratar outros projetos? É um cliente "sério", isto é, que tem necessidade e interesse no projeto, ou ele está sondando?

## Quando cobrar pela estimação

Existem exceções para o que apresentei acima. No caso de projetos demasiadamente complexos ou quando o cliente quer estimativas detalhadas, pode-se então propor um "projeto de estimação".

Nesse cenário, deve-se estimar quantas horas serão necessárias para realizar a estimação completa. Isso pode ainda incluir *wireframes*, protótipos e os documentos que deixem o cliente satisfeito.

## Conclusão

Embora não exista uma regra absoluta, posso formular alguns princípios com base no que foi apresentado:

- Estime qual o fluxo médio de novos projetos e qual o tempo médio que se leva para fazer uma boa estimação.
- Então defina um *pool* de horas mensais ou semanais para investir nos orçamentos.
- Faça com que o custo dessas horas seja diluído nas demais horas efetivamente cobradas dos clientes.
- Se um projeto de escopo grande for demandar um tempo muito acima da média, você pode optar por:

  - Investir mais horas, caso seja um cliente estratégico.
  - Informar ao cliente que um projeto desse porte exige um "projeto de estimação" (pré-estimativa), fazendo então o orçamento somente deste projeto inicial.

## Mantenha um histórico

É muito importante contabilizar o esforço gasto para negociar, estimar, escrever e-mails e tudo o mais que não faz parte de um projeto em si.

Não é incomum um projeto até simples demandar um dia inteiro no telefone e em troca de e-mails.

Anotar as horas vai aumentar a visibilidade de onde o tempo é despendido e permitirá que ajustes sejam feitos para minimizar o desperdício.

Comment: Eu ainda incluiria nas anotações de horas o tempo gasto pesquisando sobre a melhor maneira de se fazer um orçamento ou estimativa :)

Comment: O que eu conheço do Triângulo de Ferro é dizer ao cliente "Escolha dois dentro destes três itens: Alta qualidade, Execução rápida, Baixo custo, sendo que alta qualidade + execução rápida = **alto** custo; alta qualidade + baixo custo = execução **lenta**; etc".

Comment: @bfavaretto Bem verdade, seria bom contar tudo mesmo, até tempo do café e da fofoca no corredor... ;)

Comment: @utluiz +1 pela ótima resposta. Muito bem escrita, se pudesse dava +40. Eu também tinha a mesma dúvida. Com a pergunta em contexto e a sua resposta, na minha opnião, daria um ótimo artigo sobre o tema. Parabéns !

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que para estimar um orçamento você deve:

- Conhecer a solicitação do cliente
- Dividir as solicitações do cliente em tarefas
- Conhecer a capacidade da equipe
- Orçar o tempo que os membros da sua equipe vão gastar para desenvolver a solução
- Calcular os custos que você vai ter para fazer o projeto (infra, deslocamento, acomodação e etc...)

Com isso você vai ter um custo aproximado do minimo que irá gastar para fazer o serviço e não ter lucro. Quanto mais detalhado for esse levantamento inicial, mais próximo a um custo base real você vai ter. Esse calculo vai melhorando com o tempo, acrescente um percentual sobre esse valor para cobrir eventuais despesas extras. E não esquece de adicionar o seu lucro e um valor para os custos pós venda (suporte, treinamento e garantia)

Existem metodologias especificas para tratar de gerenciamento de custo o PMI é um deles.

Um link para ter mais informações, pois o que eu estou falando é bem superficial seria: http://blog.mundopm.com.br/2013/08/22/gerenciamento-de-custos/ e http://www.ufpi.br/subsiteFiles/pasn/arquivos/files/Aula09_Desenvolvendo%20o%20Orcamento%20do%20Projeto.pdf