# Quando usar RUP e quando usar Agile?

Tags: metodologia, gerenciamento-de-projetos, metodologia-ágil

Que parâmetros devo usar para determinar se um projeto terá mais sucesso se conduzido através de uma metodologia [Ágil](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desenvolvimento_%C3%A1gil_de_software) ([Scrum](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum), [XP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_extrema)), ou através do [Processo Unificado](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processo_Unificado) ([RUP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Unified_Process), [Praxis](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praxis_%28engenharia_de_software%29))? Consigo pensar em algumas características do projeto que podem se beneficiar de uma metodologia ou outra (ex.: se entregas parciais são possíveis e desejáveis, o grau de complexidade do modelo conceitual e/ou de dados, etc), mas gostaria de um quadro mais geral.

Também já me perguntei se seria aconselhável misturar os dois (ex.: [Agile Unified Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_Unified_Process) - AUP), mas para responder isso me falta uma base melhor da aplicabilidade de um e outro em cenários específicos (i.e. volta a pergunta original, quais critérios devo observar antes de adotar um ou outro).

**Contexto:** no meu entendimento, RUP e Agile têm mais em comum que, digamos, [Waterfall e Scrum](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3274/215); ambos são processos "iterativos e adaptativos", focados em construir grandes sistemas como se fossem vários sistemas menores. A principal diferença, pelo que vejo, é que no RUP há uma ênfase em se elaborar um projeto detalhado do sistema como uma fase distinta do processo, e embora se prevejam entregas parciais (chamadas "liberações") elas em geral não estão destinadas a entrar em produção (são mais para colher feedback). E a menos que eu esteja bastante enganado, não é assim que o Ágil funciona (resultados parciais poderiam sim ser colocados em produção ou ao menos homologação).

Por essa razão, estou quebrando a cabeça para determinar em que situações um é mais apropriado que o outro. A questão da entrega é uma delas, mas como tenho pouca experiência principalmente com Ágil, estou com dificuldade de enxergar os demais parâmetros nos quais eles diferem significativamente - de modo a avaliar para um projeto em particular se eles se enquadram ou não nesses parâmetros.

Comment: Tenho um colega que defende a ideia de cascata ágil, que mistura um pouco de ambos, seguindo a linha waterfall para questões de analise e levantamento de requisitos e na hora de desenvolver passa para scrum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considero a questão válida e relevante, mas tenho que admitir que isso entra um pouco no campo de opinião pessoal.

## Visão do Desenvolvedor

Como sou primariamente um **desenvolvedor**, tenho dificuldades em ver alguma vantagem num framework de processos como o RUP e outros tipos de controle como ISO, COBIT, CMMI, MPS.BR e ITIL.

Isso porque o desenvolvedor em geral está muito mais preocupado em entregar o software que foi designado para fazer. Além disso, desenvolvedores experientes sabem como fazer o seu trabalho muito bem e conseguem se auto-gerenciar.

## Visão da Equipe

Dentro de uma grande empresa, uma equipe de desenvolvimento possui uma visão pequena do todo. Isso significa que ela está a par apenas dos projetos com o qual está envolvida, mas não tem visibilidade global das diretrizes da empresa.

Os métodos ágeis são também mais atraentes para equipes porque as "empoderam" no sentido de que os envolvidos podem redefinir o processo como melhor lhes convier para entregar o que for necessário.

## Visão do Gerente

Frameworks de processos geralmente são iniciativa da gerência.

Isso porque gerentes em geral não conseguem ter uma visibilidade dos projetos do ponto de vista técnico e precisam de mecanismos "abstratos" de planejamento e acompanhamento.

A formalização e a burocracia são a forma de trazer visibilidade sobre o projeto para quem não está efetivamente participando do mesmo.

## Processos e a hierarquia

Se imaginarmos uma hierarquia, com o presidente da empresa no topo e os desenvolvedores na base, podemos dizer que os processos ágeis funcionam de baixo para cima (*bottom-up*), fluindo da equipe, enquanto os processos "tradicionais" vêm de cima para baixo (*top-down*), partindo da gerência.

Não é raro a empresa adotar formalmente um processo como o RUP ou CMMI enquanto a equipe adota um processo *scrum-like* com um gerente fazendo a interface entre um mundo e outro.

## Customização dos processos

Um ponto de vista interessante é que os processos ágeis começam com uma burocracia mínima e pode-se acrescentar ao processo o que mais for necessário. Por outro lado, frameworks com o RUP trazem um arsenal de papéis, atividades, artefatos e você precisa retirar os que você não vai usar.

No fim das contas, após passar por um processo de adaptação, o RUP pode tornar-se praticamente a mesma coisa que o Scrum, apenas com um ponto de partida diferente.

## Entregas parciais

Realmente existem projetos que demandam entregas parciais e outros com data marcada para a "entrega total". Mas o que a literatura e a experiência mostram é que o o modelo *waterfall* não funciona bem em praticamente nenhum tipo de projeto de software.

No caso de projetos com com "entrega total", o que geralmente se recomenda é gerar entregáveis e definir um "cliente" que vai testar o software executável. Pode ser um gerente, uma equipe de testes, o *product owner* ou alguém que tenha conhecimento suficiente sobre as regras de negócio.

Entretanto, na entrega para o usuário final, é inevitável um choque proporcional à quantidade de funcionalidades entregues, pois sempre haverá um *gap* entre o que foi *entendido* e o que realmente é *necessário*.

Enfim, se o cliente quer optar por uma *entrega total*, ele deve ser consciente de que o tempo necessário para ajustes não será pequeno.

E qual a diferença entre métodos ágeis e o RUP nesse sentido? Praticamente nenhuma. Observe as fases do RUP:

[image: Fases do RUP]

O RUP é dividido entre várias disciplinas, entre elas **teste** (*test*) e **entrega** (*deployment*).

Considere que a área colorida de cada disciplina representa o nível de atividade da mesma.

Desde a fase de Elaboração, o RUP já prevê atividades de teste e entrega. Aliás a ideia toda dessa fase é ter uma arquitetura executável para mitigar os maiores riscos do projeto cedo.

Voltando ao contraste entre RUP e Scrum, é claro que pode haver diferenças no tamanho da iteração e na quantidade de entregas. Considerando ainda práticas do XP, testes unitários e automação dos *builds* podem trazer grandes benefícios. Porém, tudo isso acaba mais em questões técnicas e particulares da equipe do que no processo em si.

Com exceção do XP, que possui várias definições técnicas, Scrum e RUP são abstratos demais do desenvolvimento de software para impor uma diferença muito grande.

Entretanto, algo que influencia muito no planejamento, é que o Scrum procura dar ao cliente a possibilidade de definir quais funcionalidades ele quer primeiro. A ideia é entregar ao cliente o que traz valor ao negócio o mais rápido possível.

É claro que isso diminui a flexibilidade do desenvolvedor ou gerente ao planejar. Também é algo difícil de conseguir, que causa um pouco *overhead* no desenvolvimento e exige uma capacidade considerável de quem modela e desenvolve.

É um *trade-off*. Alguns pendem para um lado, enquanto outros vão para o outro. É muito mais fácil desenvolvedor um sistema linearmente do que começar direto pelo *core* e, como pregam algumas metodologias ágeis, refatorar o sistema até que ele passe a fazer tudo o que é necessário.

## Considerações gerais

Frameworks de processos como o RUP foram concebidos como ferramentas aos gerentes. Metodologias ágeis focam na auto-organização da equipe. Em empresas, ambos acabam sendo de alguma forma necessários.

Por outro lado, os relatos em geral indicam que empreendedores, *startups* e mesmo grandes empresas de alta tecnologia têm tirado muito mais vantagem em "desburocratizar" o processo de desenvolvimento, é claro, contando com desenvolvedores experientes e altamente capacitados para isso.

Algo importantíssimo é considerar que controle, assim como qualidade, tem um custo embutido. O aumento da burocracia diminui a produtividade exponencialmente e, muitas vezes, cria entraves desnecessários. Embora isso possa ser até desejável em certos ambientes (Bancos, Bolsa de Valores, Seguradoras), não creio ser recomendável empresas nascentes, cuja dinâmica e flexibilidade são os diferenciais para conseguir entrar no mercado.

## Conclusão

O que todos podem (e deveriam) fazer é procurar entender o funcionamento e o objetivo de cada processo, além das boas práticas que cada um procura disseminar. Com esse conhecimento em mãos, é possível adotar as que forem mais importantes para o projeto sem a necessidade de adotar um rótulo de processo em si.

E algo que todos devem ter em mente, é que processo algum faz mágica na qualidade ou na produtividade. Pelo contrário, pode atrapalhar. Algo que todos concordam hoje é que:

> [Indivíduos e interação entre eles mais que processos e ferramentas](http://manifestoagil.com.br/)

Comment: "o desenvolvedor em geral está muito mais preocupado em entregar o software que foi designado para fazer" OK, mas "entregar" pode significar várias coisas: se eu sei que somente vou colocar alguma coisa em produção daqui a 6 meses, isso me dá grande flexibilidade em determinar a ordem na qual eu vou construir o sistema (ainda que eu tenha de relatar periodicamente o progresso). Se por outro lado eu prevejo entregas parciais (pelo que sei uma das diretrizes do Agile é disponibilizar mais cedo aquilo que vai agregar mais valor ao cliente), eu tenho que direcionar meu trabalho de outra maneira.

Comment: Ou seja, paradoxalmente eu sinto que tenho **mais** liberdade numa metodologia mais tradicional do que menos. Por exemplo, se eu quiser modelar o banco de dados *inteiro* antes de mexer em qualquer coisa na IU, no cenário "entrega só daqui a seis meses" eu posso. Mas se está previsto eu entregar o módulo X daqui a um mês, eu tenho que ter todos os componentes desse módulo prontos e bem testados antes de mover para as próximas tarefas. É nesse sentido que eu penso que devem haver características inerentes ao projeto que se adequariam mais a um ou outro processo. Daí a pergunta.

Comment: P.S. Tentei deixar a pergunta mais aberta, a exemplo [dessa outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3274/215), mas talvez seja sim o caso de contextualizar mais... De qualquer forma, sua resposta foi bastante útil, e trouxe coisas pra eu pensar, ainda que não fosse bem o que eu esperava.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Sobre seu segundo comentário, a liberdade do sistema tradicional não seria simplesmente no sentido em que você não precisa reportar ao cliente o que está fazendo durante o projeto? Além disso, não é necessário usar um modelo ágil puro. Modelar o banco poderia ser considerado um *executável* e pode ser testado e validado como um software qualquer. *Sprints* iniciais de modelagem são comuns.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Meu único problema com a abordagem "cascata" é que quase nunca funciona como esperado (falando de minha experiência). É muito comum modelar-se o banco todo. Na verdade foi assim em quase todos os projetos em que trabalhei. Mas é verdade também que em 100% deles houve revisão do banco, alumas muito significativas.

Comment: A liberdade que me refiro é no sentido de poder generalizar/abstrair coisas que eu sei que serão comuns desde o início do projeto. Implementar algo mais abstrato é sempre mais demorado, mas muitas vezes acaba se pagando depois. Só que se o tempo é escasso, acabo tendo que implementar algo específico primeiro e somente generalizar depois (refatorando o código, o que traz certo overhead). E eu concordo com você sobre a abordagem cascata, meu exemplo é que foi infeliz. De todo modo, pela sua resposta eu vi que você captou bem a ideia (e respondeu bem à mesma).

Comment: Meu +1 (depois das 21:00) só pela frase `vantagem em "desburocratizar" o processo de desenvolvimento, é claro, contando com desenvolvedores experientes e altamente capacitados para isso`