# Desenvolvimento de software: paradigmas

Tags: engenharia-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos, paradigma-de-programação, metodologia-ágil

Sempre ouvi e ainda ouço muitas comparações, alguém afirmando que construir **software** é equiparado a uma construção de um edifício.

Eu vejo que os engenheiros são capazes de projetar prédios dentro dos prazos e dentro do orçado com muito mais frequência do que os profissionais de TI, na verdade os profissionais de computação raramente conseguem esses "feitos".

Algumas comparações:

- Fazer um software da maneira que é feito um prédio: depois que o prédio esta pronto você não pode move-lo nenhum metro em qualquer direção, já um software virtualmente falando isso seria sim possível.
- **Construir prédios** tem etapas bem definidas e muitas delas não se pode antecipar ou inverte-las: Os planejamentos, depois os alicerces, depois os acabamentos por exemplo
- **Construir um software** sempre demanda um "vai e volta" é cheio de "idas e vindas" a medida que projeto vai avançando.

**Minha dúvida é:**

**Impor uma mão única de etapas**, bem definidas tipo: levantamento de requisitos, análise, design, implementação, testes e implantação, uma única vez como um prédio, ou seja fazer uma etapa finalizar para então começar a próxima.

ou

**Mover-se através das etapas:** ex: Aprender sobre um requisito e fazer levantamento de requisitos, análise, design, implementação, testes e implantação depois voltar as etapas e começar outro ciclo com um novo requisito, **edit:** ou seja não seguir uma metodologia e sim usar o que for necessário conforme a necessidade independente da metodologia.

Comment: Fazer software é completamente diferente de construir um edifício. Esta metáfora é invocada justamente para ser negada. Sem dúvida uma abordagem circular, com ciclos curtos de planejamento, execução e testes (tipo SCRUM) é o que mais bem funciona (ou é menos pior),

Comment: Tenho minhas dúvidas se a pergunta é adequada. Tá parecendo [Gorilla vs Shark](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101). Por outro lado, se não for, pode ser duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3274/101

Comment: Acho que a resposta para sua dúvida é depende. Logo vou tentar escrever uma reposta.

Comment: Não estou fazendo comparação entre metodologias, acho que esta mais para: seguir uma metodologia ou dançar conforme a música.

Comment: A tendência hoje são os processos iterativos e o Agile, ou seja, a segunda opção. A primeira opção é o Waterfall e é mais engessada, pelo menos para a maioria dos projetos. Mas a escolha ainda depende do tipo do projeto, como evidenciado na resposta do @PedroLaini (embora acredite que projetos aptos para o Waterfall sejam mais raros de aparecer).

Comment: @Piovezan ou seja, a pergunta é duplicada, né?

Comment: @bigown Não havia me ocorrido, mas penso que sim. Achei que talvez não fossem do conhecimento do questionador essas metodologias.

Comment: Apesar de não me referir a metodologias nem cita-las, agora que li a pergunta do @bigown me parece algo muito parecido mesmo, a diferença é que eu não tentei comparar metodologias seja ela qual for, seria usar uma ou fazer conforme a necessidade

Comment: "Eu vejo que os engenheiros são capazes de projetar prédios dentro dos prazos e dentro do orçado com muito mais frequência" Onde? Quando? Nunca vi isso não ;)

Answer (score 11):

#### Por quê o desenvolvimento de softwares assemelha-se a construção de um prédio?

Os dois processos assemelham-se pelo fato de seguirem **metodologias de desenvolvimento**. Metodologias são estratégias bastante comuns de serem utilizadas em áreas de conhecimento voltadas à engenharia, como: **Engenharia de Software** e **Engenharia Civil**. Por isso, há essa semelhança.

#### O que é metodologia?

> Entende-se por metodologia, como a maneira – forma – de se utilizar um
>   conjunto coerente e coordenado de métodos para atingir um objetivo, de
>   modo que se evite, tanto quanto possível, a subjetividade na execução
>   do trabalho. Fornecendo um roteiro, um processo dinâmico e interativo
>   para desenvolvimento estruturado de projetos, sistemas ou software,
>   visando à qualidade e produtividade dos projetos.
>
> O dicionário [WEBSTERS, 1998] define metodologia como um conjunto de
>   métodos, regras e postulados empregados por uma disciplina: um
>   procedimento particular ou conjuntos de procedimentos.

Portanto, metodologia é uma estratégia utilizada para definir **"quem", "quando", "como" e "quando" fazer as coisas.**

E é por isso que é tão importante quanto o desenvolvimento do software, escolher a metodologia adequada para o desenvolvimento de um projeto.

Não há como dizer: "O método cascata é melhor que o RUP" ou "O SCRUM é o melhor de todos os tempos". Tudo depende da necessidade do momento, da empresa e do cliente.

#### Como escolher a metodologia?

> A escolha de uma metodologia a ser utilizada no desenvolvimento, deve
>   ser realizada com base na natureza do projeto e do produto a ser
>   desenvolvido, dos métodos e ferramentas a serem utilizadas e dos
>   controles e produtos intermediários desejados.

Há 5 variáveis que precisam ser consideradas na escolha da metodologia:

> **Tempo**
>
> O tempo requerido para completar o projeto.  Por questões analíticas,
>   o tempo para concluir o projeto é dividido no tempo requerido para
>   completar cada uma das atividades que contribuem para a conclusão do
>   projeto.
>
> **Custo**
>
> É o custo do projeto, calculado a partir dos recursos utilizados.
>
> **Qualidade**
>
> O tempo dedicado às atividades individuais determinam a qualidade
>   geral do projeto.   Algumas tarefas requerem um tempo determinado para
>   que sejam completadas adequadamente, mas com tempo adicional poderiam
>   ser completadas com qualidade excepcional.   Ao longo de um projeto
>   grande, a qualidade pode ter um impacto significativo no tempo e custo
>   (ou vice-versa).
>
> **Escopo**
>
> Requerimentos especificados para o resultado final. É a definição
>   geral do que o projeto deveria atingir ou uma descrição específica de
>   qual deveria ser o resultado final.
>
> **Risco**
>
> Pontos potenciais de fracasso.  A maioria dos riscos podem ser
>   superados ou resolvidos, com suficiente tempo e recursos.

#### Conclusão

Com base nisso, para escolher uma metodologia de desenvolvimento, você precisa resolver uma "equação" do tipo `metodologia = TEMPO X CUSTO X QUALIDADE X ESCOPO X RISCO`. Isso foi apenas uma brincadeira, pois não é tão exato como uma simples equação e podem ter outras variáveis, que não foram citadas nesse post, que por algum motivo podem influenciar na escohla também.

Aí, depois que você entendeu toda a necessidade do projeto, é hora de escolher. Mas nada impede também que você desenvolva partes do projeto utilizando diferentes metodologias.

**Fontes:** [Metodologia de desenvolvimento de software](http://www.devmedia.com.br/metodologia-de-desenvolvimento-de-software/1903) e [O que é Gerenciamento de Projetos?](http://www.ogerente.com.br/projetos/dt/proj-dt-oqepj.htm):